# React Slider Issue: Images and Prev Button Not Displaying

Tags: html, reactjs, slider, react-state

I am trying to solve a react problem.
I followed the below youtube tutorial.
I am trying in code sandbox.
for some reason the  images and the prev button not showing up.
I debugged but still no luck.
Can you let me know how to fix it. Providing my code snippet below.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/image-6f5ftt?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A9%2C11

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1eO3LQ1rptA&list=PL6x5Q-Sj_Bla3_wMqhETxMBjFml0XJNPI&index=8

```
import "./styles.css";
import {useState} from 'react';
const TIMEOUT = 1000;
const SLIDES = ["https://picsum.photos/id/10/300/100",
"https://picsum.photos/id/20/300/100",
"https://picsum.photos/id/30/300/100"];
// in the props of control we don't have setSlidexIndex defined
const Controls = ({setSlidexIndex}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* // we don't know whatindex is it */}
      <button onClick={() => {
        setSlideIndex((curIndex) =>{
          // in callback function what ever we return from the function is the new value of the state
          return curIndex - 1 < 0 ? SLIDES.length - 1 : curIndex - 1 ;
        })
      }}>Prev</button>
      <button>Next</button>
      <button>Play</button>
      <button>Stop</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Slide = ({ slideNumber }) => {
  <img src={SLIDES[slideNumber]} alt="" />;
};
const slider = () => {
  const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(0);
  return({
    <div>
    // two components need to state so we need to ellevate state
    <Slide slideNumber ={slideIndex}/>
    <Controls setSlideIndex={setSlideIndex}/>
    <div/>
  });
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a typo in your Controls prop initialization you typed slidexIndex.
2. The Slide component is missing a return statement. You need to return the JSX.
3. The return statement of the slider component is incorrect. It should be parentheses () instead of curly braces {}.
   I have checked the below code and it is working as expected.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

const TIMEOUT = 1000;
const SLIDES = [
  "https://picsum.photos/id/10/300/100",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/20/300/100",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/30/300/100",
];

const Controls = ({ setSlideIndex }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setSlideIndex((curIndex) => {
            return curIndex - 1 < 0 ? SLIDES.length - 1 : curIndex - 1;
          });
        }}
      >
        Prev
      </button>
      <button>Next</button>
      <button>Play</button>
      <button>Stop</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Slide = ({ slideNumber }) => {
  return <img src={SLIDES[slideNumber]} alt="" />;
};

const Slider = () => {
  const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <Slide slideNumber={slideIndex} />
      <Controls setSlideIndex={setSlideIndex} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Slider />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, can you let me know how you found this errors. So that in future I can fix it myself

Comment: If this is correct answer please mark it in the answer, It will help me.
Nothing much you will understand with the experience. Better use proptypes in react if you are implementing props for your component. 
You can search over internet about this topic.